# Why doesn't gir1.2-vips-8.0 contain Vips.Image.grey?

Tags: python, 20.04

When installed via pyvips into a venv Vips.Image.grey is working but with `gir1.2-vips-8.0` this code fails because `grey` is not found:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Vips', '8.0')
from gi.repository import Vips

null_image = Vips.Image.grey(1, 1)
```

Edit: I specifically want to avoid using `pyvips` because it's the only dependency for the [script](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/blob/80e32f911baeab18599f4c6bea07deff7226e241/tools/gfx_tools/compose.py#L14) I'm running and I want to not bother about activating `venv`.

Comment: In their tests [they use](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/blob/002b2a28e1ffc0019e443d23fc0ec8307dc06611/test/test-suite/test_histogram.py#L114) `import pyvips`, followed by `pyvips.Image.grey(...)`. You have to read somewhere about the Python VIPS API.

Comment: Thank you, I know, that was supposed to be covered by the start of the first sentence. Why would the method I've added differ, that's the question. It's more convenient as I wouldn't have to remember activating the venv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the old gobject-introspection Python interface. It was slow, unstable and inflexible. It will give you poor performance and frequent, inexplicable crashes.

It was replaced quite a few years ago by the much better [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). Just `pip install pyvips`, then:

```
import pyvips
image = pyvips.Image.grey(100, 100)
```

Comment: Ok, from now on I'll just downvote every suggestion to use `pyvips`. `pyvips` may be great, I don't deny it. But the question is specifically about trying to avoid using it and you are the third person out of three who responded who didn't take that into account.

Comment: I think I overreacted, please edit the answer so I could remove the downvote.

Comment: Ah don't worry, I overreact all the time. I didn't mean to be unhelpful, it's just that libvips via g-o-i does not work well, and it will cause you problems. It really will crash. I would not have spent all that time writing pyvips unless I had a very strong reason heh.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `grey` is not a direct dependency of `libvips` or `libvips42` which is in turn a dependency package `gir1.2-vips-8.0`.

On the other hand, if you install it via `pip` in an `venv` it is being pulled by python as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean that `grey` is not a dependency? `grey` is not a package, it's a method in this library and there are a lot of methods available in `Vips.Image` when imported from `gi.repository`, what's the reason that `grey` is not there?

Comment: Created this question for pyvips https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/199

Comment: what is the version of installed package `pyvips` within your `venv` ? and what is the version of `libvips42`  on your system?

Comment: Again, `pyvips` is not relevant here, the question is specifically about trying to avoid it. `libvips42` is `8.9.1-2`.